# PayPalでクレジットカードで決済した後、リダイレクトは自動的に行われない。

Tags: paypal

バイヤーがクレジットカード決済方法で決済した後、決済完了画面が表示されるまま、リダイレクトは自動的に行われない。HTMLのFormでPayPalのボタンを作成しましたが、自動復帰機能もアカウントで有効に設定しています。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PayPalのウェブペイメントスタンダードを利用している、かつ買い手様がクレジットカードで決済する場合では、
決済完了画面で「******のページに戻る」のリンクまたはボタンが表示され、そのリンクをクリックしないとリダイレクトされないのは仕様です。
ただ、そのリンクのテキストを変更することはできます。
HTMLのフォームに、"cbt"というパラメータを設定すれば、そのリンクのテキストをカスタマイズできます。
"cbt"パラメータの詳細は下記ページで"cbt"を検索してください。
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/

ちなみに、ウェブペイメントプラスサービスを利用すれば、バイヤーがクレジットカードで支払った直後にマーチャントのサイトに自動的にリダイレクトすることが可能になります。
ウェブペイメントプラスの場合、取引ごとの手数料以外に、月額手数料があります、具体的には下記のページをご参考ください。
https://www.paypal.jp/jp/contents/service/web-payment-plus/
インテグレーションガイドも上記URLに含まれています。

PayPalではテクニカルサポートの部署がありますので、何かPayPal実装関連の質問や技術的な質問がありましたら、下記URLで記事を検索してみてください。
https://jp.paypal-techsupport.com/
上記URLの一番下の「お問い合わせ」リンクをクリックしてまたは下記URLをアクセスして質問を送信してください。
https://jp.paypal-techsupport.com/app/ask